# Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO) for some reason?

Tags: php

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","123456","astralms");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$username = htmlspecialchars(mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['username']));

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE name = '$username'");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
    echo $row['gm'];
    echo "<>";
    echo $row['vpoints'];
    echo "<>";
    echo $row['ACash'];
   }
?>
```

This is my code. All the information is 100% correct. However, even though I did put a password, it acts like I didn't.

Why's that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You have a `mysqli` connection, so instead of using mysql_real_escape_string(), you'll want to use [`mysqli_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)

The error you're seeing is due to mysql_real_escape_string() trying to establish its own connection, since no connection using the old api is active.

EDIT: `mysqli_real_escape_string` takes the connection to the database as the first parameter, so in your case you'd call it like;

```
mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['username'])
```

Comment: What is the second paramter I have to use for mysqli_real_escape_string? I found an answer online, but what is the "link"?

Comment: @JohnReakon Connection link, you need to use `$con`

Answer (score 3):

You are using a call to the old, deprecated `mysql` function for the call to `mysql_real_escape_string`.

The two extensions have different connections, do not mix them.

A call to an escaping function needs an active connection, because the escaping has to know the current encoding setting. The mysql extension did not have a connection and is opening one with default parameters from php.ini. Luckily for you, it didn't work with these.